# lightweight SVG viewer

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, graphics

Sometimes I want to look quickly at a large number of SVG files.  My options seem to be Inkscape, which is rather ponderous and slow to open, or a browser, which is unsatisfactory for other reasons.  Is there a tool that does nothing but display (not edit) SVG images?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have quite the diverse range of options:

Free:

[Gapplin (AppStore)](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gapplin/id768053424) 14MB

[macSVG 9MB](https://macsvg.org/)

> macSVG is a MIT-licensed open-source macOS application for designing and editing Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) content for HTML5 web pages, mobile apps, animation design, and general graphics usage.

[SVGViewer](http://blue-tail.com/svgviewer/)

> Fast, Free and Simple SVGViewer file Viewer
>   Open and export SVG files on Mac, send to friends. Download SVGViewer for Mac. It’s free!

And with an additional footprint of 0 bytes:

- your favourite browser!

Comment: Thank you, Gapplin should do nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this question pretty late.  Another option is to use [svg-edit](https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit)  It is browser based, and you can download the entire application and runs in your web browser.

They also have an online version. see [SVG editor](https://svg-edit.github.io/svgedit/editor/svg-editor.html)